# chromium webdriver can't reach the instagram login page

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently working on instagram login script, however i cannot even reach instagram login page with below code, is that the "chromedriver" is being blocked or any idea of my chromedriver configuration or whats wrong am I ?!!

This is my code:

```
# chromium-chromedrive (Not Python Library)
#!apt-get update # Update OS Files
#!apt install chromium-chromedriver
#!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
#!pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import sys

##################################################################
# Add The System Path
##################################################################
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/bin/chromedriver')

##################################################################
# Config The Chrome Driver Setting In Python
##################################################################
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")            #bypass OS security model
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=chrome_options)

print("Loading Instagram")
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?hl=en")
print(driver.page_source)
```

It return "...Error Please wait a few minutes before you try again...."

I have tried to (1)remove cookies OR (2)change server IP (using Singapore / US Region IP)  OR (3)even using google colab . Same result return. Anymore idea/method that I should try?

P.S. No such problem if i open instagram with my Ubuntu Chrome (With GUI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to load Instagram with the code below. Make sure you are using the latest version of chrome driver. https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

```
#Importing selenium
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver


#chromedriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


#defining driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())


#opeining instagram
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?hl=en')
```

Comment: Same problem even latest chromedriver, you will get "...... .Page Not Found • Instagram ........" when u call "driver.page_source" (which means it is a instagram webpage, but all instagram function inside are not accessible), you have tried the one in colab? which server or machine you have used to test? Any OS version can provide to me?

Comment: Also, i added 'chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")' as i have terminal only

Comment: I forgot to mention you need a package called chromedriver manager.

Comment: yes, tried that one, but still no luck in chromedriver to visit IG page. u can test in google colab to run it, u will get same result as me ~